# Mysql limit joined table results by previous table column

Tags: mysql, sql, join, mysql-5.6, lateral-join

I have three tables: `test_composite`, `tests`, `questions`. TestComposite belongs to Test. Test has many Questions.

```sql
create table test_composite
(
    id                 bigint unsigned auto_increment
        primary key,
    id_include_test    bigint unsigned   not null,
    questions_quantity smallint unsigned not null,
)
```

```sql
create table tests
(
    id                  bigint unsigned auto_increment
        primary key,
    name                varchar(128)  not null,
)
```

```sql
create table questions
(
    id         bigint unsigned auto_increment
        primary key,
    question   text            not null,
    test_id    bigint unsigned not null,
)
```

The question is how to make this query work:

```sql
select questions.*
from test_composite
         inner join tests on test_composite.id_include_test = tests.id
         inner join questions on questions.id in (
    select id 
    from questions 
    where tests.id = questions.test_id limit test_composite.questions_quantity
);
```

This query is expected to join `test_composite` and `tests` tables and then join questions with limit scope. Therefore everything comes to using previous table data in current table query.

Problem is that `limit test_composite.questions_quantity` isn't allowed.

Is there any way to do it?

PS. Mysql version 5.6.

> I know a little about lateral join, but it is not supported in 5.6 version.

Comment: "Make this query work".  You need to explain what you want the query to do.

Comment: use PARTITION BY